# IN operator mysql

Tags: mysql, operators, mysql-workbench

I have a question about the IN operator and how it might apply to simulating an 'EXCEPT' 
query. So i've read that INTERSECT and EXCEPT doesn't exist in MySQL and that the way around this is to use IN and NOT IN operators.
eg.

```
SELECT column1 FROM table1
WHERE column1 IN (SELECT column1 FROM table2);  -- INTERSECT

SELECT column1 FROM table1
WHERE column1 NOT IN (SELECT column1 FROM table2); -- EXCEPT
```

So my question has to do with how IN works; as far as i understand it, it's kinda like a long OR statement. So when using the code above does it not stop once one of the rows have been matched? Thereby only returning 1 column that matches. Or does IN check all rows in a column regardless of whether a match has already been found.

Comment: I would be use an inner join for intersect and a simulated full join (with null tests)for except.

Comment: If you want to use subquery, you can use EXISTS / NOT EXISTS instead of IN / NOT IN

Comment: EXISTS/NOT EXISTS makes more sense because i'm assuming it will check all the records in column1 from table2 and not just stop at the first match.
was my thinking correct that the IN operator will stop at the first match?
@p.salmon i'm not sure what you mean. could you provide some code as an example?